# Angular 4 | window.scrollTo(); is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Currently, I'm trying to automatically scroll to the top of the HTML page for which I'm using in my Typescript.

```
 window.scrollTo(0 , 0);
```

and while trying to automatically scroll down to bottom of the HTML page

```
 window.scrollTo( 0 , document.body.scrollHeight);
```

- I'm trying to scroll top after an HTTP response.

**Code**

```
 openPDFVievwer(data) {
  this.obj= JSON.parse(data._body);
  document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'none';
  window.scrollTo( 0 , 0);
}
```

- when I'm trying to scroll bottom after rendering another component.

**Code**

```
searchData(data) {
    this.document = data;
    this.searchResultDiv = true; // where component will be rendered
    window.scrollTo( 0 , document.body.scrollHeight);
  }
```

but, both seem to be not working.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is that you are trying to do. you can simply use `scrollTop` to do a scrolling

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try into html

```
<div #list [scrollTop]="list.scrollHeight"></div>
```

Solution 2

In Component
define id into html `id="scrollId"`

```
const element = document.querySelector('#scrollId');
element.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Actually, your second solution worked for me.but with slight modification.I used `document.getElementById` instead of querySelector. Thanks :)

Comment: If use it in an innerhtml can use `scrollIntoView()` and `window.scrollTo( 0 , 0)`

Answer (score 4):

Answer for **angular 2+**

It's very simple,
Just create an any element

e.g.
 `<span id="moveTop"></span>` or **add just id** into the element or use already existed Id where **you have to *move top, down, mid*** etc.

and add this method on specific event, like I want to move top when edit as my list list too much.

```
 gotoTop() {

   var scrollElem= document.querySelector('#moveTop');
   scrollElem.scrollIntoView();  
  }
```

or If you want to send Id as Parameter you simply just **create Optional Parameter**

```
gotoTop(elementId?: string) {

    if (elementId != null) {
        var element = document.querySelector(elementId);
        element.scrollIntoView();
    } 
    else {
        var element = document.querySelector('#moveTop');
        element.scrollIntoView();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Above solution wasn't working for me, Try this
**code:**

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router: Router)
ngOnInit()
   {
     this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
    if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
    return;
      }
  document.getElementsByTagName("app-website-nav")[0].scrollIntoView();
});
   }
```

Comment: Great snippet, but how can we make the scrolling **smooth**?